# Harmonic number of $r$ with order $r$

Tags: syntax, summation, series-expansion

Mathematica recently offered me this expression as the result of an evaluation: `HarmonicNumber[r, -r]`. I initially thought this must be equivalent to `Sum[1/k^r, {k, 1, r}]`, but it appears I'm wrong:

```
TrueQ[HarmonicNumber[r, -r] == Sum[1/k^r, {k, 1, r}]]
```

> `False`

Can someone please tell me what the equivalent of `HarmonicNumber[r, -r]` is when written in `Sum` form? I'm sure it's a dumb question (and I'm sure I could ask MMA to do it for me, if I only knew how), but I'd appreciate an answer nonetheless.

Comment: That's not what `TrueQ` is for. Please check its documentation.

Comment: Have you looked under Details and Options in the documentation of `HarmonicNumber`? The sum form is given there for any integer input value.

Comment: OK I will, and thank you. But can you please tell me how I *can* find what `HarmonicNumber[r, -r]` means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were only missing a sign:

```
HarmonicNumber[r, -r] == Sum[1/k^-r, {k, 1, r}]
```

> True

Comment: Thanks Henrik. I thought I was being dumb! I'll mark as read when the timer allows.

Comment: Richard, you are always welcome.